# Clarification needed for proof of infinitely many primes of the form $4k+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, congruences, arithmetic-progressions

I am almost done with my proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+3$, but have one remaining concern.

My chosen $N$, the subject of my contradictions, is defined as $4(p_1p_2\cdots p_n-1)+3$ where $p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ are the finite primes of the form $4k+3$ (assumed finite earlier for contradiction.)

My proof hinges on the fact that none of the $p_i$'s can divide $N$ without remainder. I claim that this is by "construction of $N$," but lack the more rigorous proof. Any tips?

Comment: Notice that $4(p_1 ... p_n -1) +3 = 4p_1 ... p_n -1$ so that $N$ cannot be divisible by any of the $p_i$.

Comment: See my comment under Jack d'Aurizio's answer. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof goes along the following lines: assume that $3=p_1,7=p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_m$ are some distinct primes of the form $4k+3$. The huge number
$$ N = -1+4\prod_{j=1}^{m}p_j $$
is $\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, hence it must have a prime divisor $\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. However, neither $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{m-1}$ or $p_m$ are divisors of $N$, since they all divide $N+1$, hence there must be an extra prime number of the form $4k+3$.

---

A similar approach is to construct a sequence of integers $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with the properties that $a_n\equiv -1\pmod{4}$ for every $n\geq 1$, and for every $m>n\geq 1$
$$ \gcd(a_n,a_m)=1 $$
holds. It follows that there must be at least one different prime of the form $4k+3$ for each element of the sequence. A sequence fulfilling such constraints is, for instance,
$$ a_1=3,\qquad a_n = -1+4\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k.$$

Comment: Why make it a proof by contradiction?  Don't assume these are all of the primes of the form $4k+3$ that exist; just assume they are $m$ of them. They don't even need to be the _smallest_ $m$ of them. Then conclude that the prime divisor of $N$ that's congruent to $-1$ must be some prime that was not among those $m$ of them; hence there are more primes of that form. $\qquad$

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The question seems to be asking for tips on how to show that none of the $p_i$s are divisors of $N$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: a fine way. The constructivist choice? :D

Comment: @Duncan: five words added to explain that point.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : The simpler and less confusing choice.  Here are the problems. Euclid wrote that is $S$ is any finite set of primes, then the prime factors of $1+\prod S$ are not in $S$, so there are always more primes than those in $S$. Many modern authors, probably starting with Dirichlet in the 1850s, have ERRONEOUSLY said Euclid wrote it as a proof by contradiction, assuming $S$ contains all primes. Firstly, that makes the proof appear more complicated than it is by adding a pointless complication.  Secondly, some authors write "This number, not being divisible by$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$any prime, therefore must itself by prime.  But that is a contradiction." Students read that and mistakenly think they've read a proof that if $S$ is the set of the first several primes, then $1+\prod S$ must be prime.  But that has counterexamples. Then they try to prove the twin prime conjecture by saying $\pm1+\prod S$ are both prime. Then they find out that what they thought was proved has lots of counterexamples and they mistakenly conclude that Euclid was wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I saw that situation with my own eyes, too. Contradiction removed from the above lines ;)